# Onclick keeps going back to its original value

Tags: javascript, html

Was trying to make a minesweeper in javascript and ran into this problem...

I created a table and each td is a "box" with either a mine or nothing(Currently) in it.
After I click on a box, the javascript should change the onclick from "clicked(this.id)" to an alert that says "NOPE"(made an alert just to test if something was happening), but what happends is:

1. I click on "box 1", it reveals what's there (bomb or nothing)
2. I click on it again, this time I get an alert "NOPE" - which means the onclick has changed. Good!
3. I click on "box 2", it reveals what's there (bomb or nothing)
4. I click on it again, this time I get an alert "NOPE" - which means this onclick has changed too!
5. I click on "box 1" again. The clicked(this.id) runs again. (This is shown because I added a counter for each time the function runs)

For some reason, the onclick returns to its original value (clicked(this.id))..

I made a test page, a table with 2 td's and the same thought in mind(change onclick value after it's clicked) and it works.. I have no idea how to fix this...

The test.html that does work:
http://pastebin.com/62ayRJps

The HTML from the site that doesn't work as intended:
http://pastebin.com/SZ6NU8j9

And the Javascript from the site that doesn't work as intended:
http://pastebin.com/bevJHNLc

Comment: If you want to provide a JavaScript sample, use a JSFiddle because it is interactive: http://jsfiddle.net/QAnHL/

Comment: It won't let me just link to jsfiddle

Comment: @user1021085 The reason for that was also displayed to you; you need to include relevant code inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your click event handlers are being reset because of this line in `clicked(id)`:

```
document.getElementById("minesweeper").innerHTML += ammountClicked+" - "
```

Each table cell has a `onclick='clicked(this.id);'` attribute in its HTML. When you assign your test function `tst` to the table cell DOM object, you're setting the `onclick` property of the DOM object, but that doesn't change the `onclick` attribute of the HTML. (Yes, it's confusing.)

In the line of code above, the browser reads the `innerHTML` from the minesweeper `div` (which has the original `onclick` attributes), concatenates it with another string, then reassigns the result back to the minesweeper `div`. This wipes out the original contents of the `div` and replaces it with the new HTML (a table where every cell has the original `onclick` attribute).

---

If you want to have a message area, I suggest setting `innerHTML` on another element: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/DqLEU/)

In the demo, I changed line 49 (adding a `span`):

```
print += "</table><span id='message'></span>";
```

and line 107 (assigning the text to the `span`):

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += ammountClicked+" - ";
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you keep track of the state of each item.  It's best not to modify code while running your application.

```
var states = {1: 0, 2: 0};

function clicked(id)
{
    if (states[id] === 0)
      alert("First time clicking me, eh?");
    else
      alert("Seems we have a repeat offender!");

    states[id]++;
}
```

This lets you split the logic in your function by checking if the `state` for a given `id` has been changed (e.g., by a previous click).

[interactive demo on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ifufoz/6/edit)

Answer (score 0):

With a few modifications in `function clicked(id)` it can work:

1. comment line `//document.getElementById(id).onclick = tst;`
2. add `field[row][column] = false;` at the end of the function
3. check if field contains `false` before performing any actions:

   ```
   if (field[row][column] == false) {
       console.log("This cell has already been clicked");
       return;
   }
   ```

There is no need to change onclick events.

The problem, as explained by **Jeffery To** is the following:

1. you click on cell **0,0**
2. function `clicked` is called
3. `minesweeper.innerHTML = minesweeper.innerHTML + "1 - "` [all onclick events resetted]
4. onclick event of cell 0,0 is changed
5. you click on a new cell, **0,1** for example
6. `minesweeper.innerHTML = minesweeper.innerHTML + "2 - "` [all onclick events resetted]
7. onclick event of cell **0,1** is changed

onclick events are resetted because innerHTML contains all the onclick declarations. It is like rewriting all the HTML of that div, and thus rewriting all child elements and its events.
This is also the reason why your simple example (the one with just two cells) works.