# Appending innerHTML without creating a Node

Tags: html, domdocument

I have an element like below. I want to remove the blockquote present inside and replace them by its innerHTML

```
 <blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;">
     <blockquote style="margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;">HTML</blockquote>
     <blockquote style="margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;">Java</blockquote>
 </blockquote>
```

to

```
 <blockquote style="margin: 0 0 0 40px; border: none; padding: 0px;">
     HTML<br>
     Java<br>
 </blockquote>
```

How can I do this? I know a way to achieve this by creating another node(like span/div) and then replace the . But I don't want to add any other elements and want only its innerHTML elements. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use jquery you can do this:

```
$('blockquote > blockquote').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).after(text + '<br />');
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/cjsuV/

for YUI DOM you can use:

```
YUI().use('node', function(Y) {
  var blockQuotes = Y.all('blockquote > blockquote');
  blockQuotes.each(function (blockQuote) {
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(blockQuote.get('innerHTML'));
    var brNode = document.createElement('br');
    blockQuote.insert(brNode, 'after');
    blockQuote.insert(textNode, 'after');
    blockQuote.remove();
  });
});
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/cjsuV/4/

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a way to achieve this through native DOM API.(have to use with YUI DOM :'(.. )

Comment: Have added a YUI DOM example, weird language!

Comment: Thanks, although you solution works looks good. it doesn't work in all cases, when there are <span><p> tags inside <blockquote>, they will be interpreted as "TEXT" inside textNode and not as HTML element.

Comment: are you only going to have blockquotes as children of the main blockquote?

Comment: Yes, but the innerHTML of those blockquotes can have simple text or HTML elements

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
document.getElementById("your-element").innerHTML = "HTML<br>Java<br>";
```

Or if you want to append:

```
document.getElementById("your-element").innerHTML += "HTML<br>Java<br>";
```

*Note*: overwriting `innerHTML` of an element may cause problems. For example if you have `onclick` events. See more:

- [Adding to innerHTML correct syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977179/adding-to-innerhtml-correct-syntax/14977267#14977267)
- [Onclick keeps going back to its original value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446006/onclick-keeps-going-back-to-its-original-value/14725744#14725744)

Comment: sorry @Sriharsha, made a mistake. `innerHTML` is not a method hehe. First code example was wrong, now it is ok. sorry.